# Html5 Validation or Functionality - can´t I get both?

Tags: php, facebook, html

I have this Link giving a share possibility to facebook.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?display=popup&u=<?php echo urlencode($this->Environment->base . $this->Environment->request); ?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($this->title); ?>" rel="nofollow" title="Auf Facebook teilen" target="blank"  onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'width=760,height=570,modal=yes,left=100,top=50,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no'); return false;"><img src="system/modules/news4ward/html/social/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="30" height="30"></a>
```

My problem with it is, it won´t validate in an HTML5 document. Changing the `&` to `%26` will fix validation but breaks the facebook sharing as it doesn't fetch the open graph descriptions.

What can I do?

Comment: Try changing it to `&amp;`

Comment: omg i first tried this   but i don´t know why it didnt validate with it in the past.  now it works perfectly - thx

Comment: Why not post this as an answer so the OP can accept it to save others from clicking on the question? :) Glad you got it sorted OP.

Comment: @JoelMurphy You're right, I've posted an answer now. The comment was just the first thought I had ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the original ampersand `&` to the HTML entity `&amp;`